# How do I retrieve text from a text file and save it to a string using C#?

Tags: c#, text-files, external, notepad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq To Text Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720074/linq-to-text-files)

I have a .txt file in  C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\ named file.txt. How do I retrieve text from this file and store it into a string using C# without having to open the file with Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); ?

In addition, How do I write a string, on the same notepad file and save changes?

Answer (score 1):

To read it as one string from the file use:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` or `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
         }
```

A simple Google search gives you the above answer...