# C#: how to perform a SQL query on a flat file?

Tags: c#, sql, flat-file

In the past I was able to use SQL select statements on a flat file from VBA from within Excel.

How can I do something similar in C# using VS 2013?

As an overview, I'm creating a desktop app that needs to search a static table of ~100k rows and 6 columns and I'm thinking it doesn't warrant incorporating a real db.

Any pointers or other ideas out there?

Fred

Comment: If you put the data into a db, then it's accessible from more than one computer.

Comment: You can try with oledb http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is made for this. It's a layer between 'something' (text file, database, XML etc.) and the LINQ language. Take a look here.

[Linq To Text Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720074/linq-to-text-files)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a great tool for querying different filetypes: It's called [log parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13504/Simple-log-parsing-using-MS-Log-Parser-in-C-NE) .

I personally use it for parsing IIS logs ( *.csv)

Have fun ;-)